# Creating a PHP function

Tags: php

So I'm trying to create a PHP function to track my visitors. The reason why I want a function of it is because I do not want to copy/paste the code to every page where I'll be using the tracker. Now I must confess that PHP functions are my weakest. Any help would be appreciated.

**This is my current function:**

```
function visitor_ip_data($ip_city) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['ip_country']) || !isset($_SESSION['ip_city']) || !isset($_SESSION['ip_postal']) || !isset($_SESSION['ip_region']) || !isset($_SESSION['ip_isp']) ) {
        //Niet geset, haal nieuwe IP data op
        $url = file_get_contents('http://api.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/v1.8/locateip?key=MY-KEY-GOES-HERE&ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&format=JSON');
        $html = json_decode($url);

        if ($html->query_status->query_status_code != 'OK') {
            //API data ERROR
            //Destroy the SESSIONS
            unset($_SESSION['ip_city']);
            unset($_SESSION['ip_postal']);
            unset($_SESSION['ip_region']);
            unset($_SESSION['ip_country']);
            unset($_SESSION['ip_isp']);

            //echo "Error! ".$html->query_status->query_status_description." ";
            //die();
        } else {
            //API data SUCCESS
            //Create SESSIONS
            $feed = $html->geolocation_data;

            $_SESSION['ip_city'] = $feed->city;
            $_SESSION['ip_postal'] = $feed->postal_code;
            $_SESSION['ip_region'] = $feed->region_name;
            $_SESSION['ip_country'] = $feed->country_name;
            $_SESSION['ip_isp'] = $feed->isp;

            $ip_city = $_SESSION['ip_city'];
            $ip_postal = $_SESSION['ip_postal'];
            $ip_region = $_SESSION['ip_region'];
            $ip_country = $_SESSION['ip_country'];
            $ip_isp = $_SESSION['ip_isp'];

            //echo "Gathered IP data from API";
            //die();
        } 

    } else {
        //IP data are already in sessions
        //use the sessions
        $ip_city = $_SESSION['ip_city'];
        $ip_postal = $_SESSION['ip_postal'];
        $ip_region = $_SESSION['ip_region'];
        $ip_country = $_SESSION['ip_country'];
        $ip_isp = $_SESSION['ip_isp'];

        //echo "Using IP data from sessions";
        //die();
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is echoíng the $ip_city on a page using the function. Part of the page code is as following:

```
echo visitor_ip_data($ip_city);
```

But that gives me the Undefined Variable error message. Now I'm wondering why it's doing that. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

THank you.

Comment: One of the indexes of an array you are trying to access is not defined. What is the error message?

Comment: show your full error message. thanks.

Comment: Use a ternary operator on your `$feed->` assignments.`$_SESSION['ip_city'] = isset($feed->city) ? $feed->city : false;` etc... If your function does not always expect an ip_city to be passed to it, set it to false by default. `function visitor_ip_data($ip_city = false);`

Comment: Well when I echo out the variables INSIDE of the function and echo the function, it works fine. The error message is: Undefined variable: ip_city.

Comment: it means there is no variable exist  `$ip_city` that you passed to your function.

Comment: See about scopes here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything from function.

Remove argument from function definition : `function visitor_ip_data()`

Write

```
      //echo "Error! ".$html->query_status->query_status_description." ";
      return NULL;

    } else {
        //API data SUCCESS
        //Create SESSIONS
        $feed = $html->geolocation_data;

        $_SESSION['ip_city'] = $feed->city;
        $_SESSION['ip_postal'] = $feed->postal_code;
        $_SESSION['ip_region'] = $feed->region_name;
        $_SESSION['ip_country'] = $feed->country_name;
        $_SESSION['ip_isp'] = $feed->isp;

        $data['ip_city'] =  = $_SESSION['ip_city'];
        $data['ip_postal'] = $_SESSION['ip_postal'];
        $data['ip_region'] = $_SESSION['ip_region'];
        $data['ip_country'] = $_SESSION['ip_country'];
        $data['ip_isp'] = $_SESSION['ip_isp'];

        //echo "Gathered IP data from API";
        //die();
    } 

} else {
    //IP data are already in sessions
    //use the sessions
    $data['ip_city'] = $_SESSION['ip_city'];
    $data['ip_postal'] = $_SESSION['ip_postal'];
    $data['ip_region'] = $_SESSION['ip_region'];
    $data['ip_country'] = $_SESSION['ip_country'];
    $data['ip_isp'] = $_SESSION['ip_isp'];

    //echo "Using IP data from sessions";
    //die();
    }
    return $data;
```

And then

```
if (($data = visitor_ip_data()) == NULL) echo 'error';
else echo $data['ip_city'];
```

Comment: Cant get it to work, meh.. :|

Comment: @monkeybread I wrote in detail

Comment: Thanks! I had to edit it a bit since I have to store the value of the variables in my database. if (($data = visitor_ip_data()) == NULL) $ip_city =  ''; else $ip_city = $data['ip_city']; echo $ip_city;  did the trick. Thanks man, learned something from you. Highly appreciated!